# 1 error popup. Have tried debugging javascript, thinking of giving up

Tags: javascript, magento, popup, modal-dialog

My current system is Magento. It seems to only happen on this page. Perhaps there is someone out there with a better debugger than I.

I've stepped through it and have tried to find out where this message is coming from.

I've deleted several files but still can't seem to find it.

http://tombalding.com/bit-creator.html

When you open the page it will say Prevent this page from showing additional dialog. I've google this error and have spent several hours trying to debug this.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something on the frontent. But can't seem to find where the message is being generated from.

Any help will be well appreciated and I will document my changes on here in case someone else has the same issue.

Comment: You have `alert(1);` in plain sight in your page source, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: On the [main page](http://tombalding.com/) there is a large message that says "You might experience a bug or two ... but it will be done soon." So you might just need to wait until it goes away.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for avoiding any alert in production code is  by redefining the alert function on top of the page inside a `script` tag or the first js file you load.

> window.alert = function(){};

For you case however, Search for alert(1) in your page source code

Answer (score 1):

Check for alert function in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Actually for anyone hating out there on my question. The answers given here might have seemed simple to some. But for me it was a tough find. I've downloaded all my script and did search for and comment out the alert(1).

Strangely I couldn't find that for whatever reason. Thankfully there are people out there who, even when something might seem small, have the kindness to help.

Thank you for your help.

I found this alert by downloading my script and searching all of it using notepad++